# ajax callback return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

in last 2 days I tried to solve my problem. Now I need help.  My task is very simple. Jquery ajax request posts a user name and a password to server, where is python framework "Flask". I did very simple example, but it still doesn't work.

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: values, //(json with username and password)
                    complete:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }

                });
```

I tried to rewrite success and error function, but result is the same.
Everything returns:

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", more...}
```

Flask implementation:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_page():

    return jsonify(redirect="index.html")
```

Headers:

response:

```
Content-Length  30
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Sun, 20 Oct 2013 09:50:19 GMT
Server  Werkzeug/0.9.3 Python/2.7.3
Set-Cookie  session=eyJfaWQiOnsiIGIiOiJOakkwTUdVM01HVXhNR0prWmpka05qQXlPRGcwT1dWbFlUQmhPRGRpT0RrPSJ9fQ.BUU42w.FDnVp15DxEsMPP_TsOpq8OzzU5I; HttpOnly; Path=/
```

request:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language cs,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  102
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    127.0.0.1:5000
Origin  http://localhost
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost/login.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

I tried  to return a redirection, and console network log shows me this returning, but I have found the ajax doesn't redirect (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256609/2107985).
Every time console.log from ajax function shows me "error", although there is 200 OK.

By manually typing link: `http://localhost:5000/login` to the browser, it returns json normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request says `Origin  http://localhost` but the URL you are requesting is `http://localhost:5000/login`.

Your console should be giving you the warning:

> Origin `http://localhost` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Your ability to read the data is limited by [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  You either need to use the same origin for both requests or [circumvent it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: no warning. I added [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9570852/2107985) data to headers, but it didn't help.

Comment: What, exactly, do the response headers say now? And what does the response body look like?

Comment: response header has new rows: Access-Control-Allow-Head... Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Meth...HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS,
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...* and body contains {"redirect": "index.html"}

Comment: Looking at the requests being made, do you see an OPTIONS request? Is it successful?

Comment: Yes and its status was 200 OK, but from ajax I got error again :(

Comment: Now, it is working :) Between some steps I add contentType:"json", after removing it, everything is fine ;) But I don't understand why.