# Flask: redirect(url_for()) returning html but not loading page

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I am building a small web app in Flask, a code excerpt is below. Basically, I am trying to store some data in `startsession` and then move on to `tagpage` once this is achieved. But `redirect` is not working.

When I run `TEST 1`, it displays `hello, world` in the console but the main page looks the same.
When I run `TEST 2`, it displays the html in the console but the main page looks the same.

Here is what I have:

```
@app.route('/startsession', methods=['POST'])
def startsession(): 
    _username = request.form['inputName']
    session['user_name'] = _username    
    ...
    return  redirect(url_for('tagpage'))
```

Then, either:

```
### TEST 1
@app.route("/tagpage")
def tagpage():
    return "hello, world"
```

Or:

```
### TEST 2
@app.route("/tagpage")
def tagpage():
    return render_template('tagpage.html', filename=filename)
```

Sample of what I see after clicking the button that triggers `startsession`:

[image]

How can I get the browser to actually go to `http://localhost:5000/tagpage`?

UPDATE:
Here is my JQuery script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnStartSession").click(function(){     
        $.ajax({
            url: '/startsession',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });             


    });
});
```

Comment: Are you posting to `/startsession` with javascript or a form?

Comment: Your code might raise errors since the route and class names for your test routes are identical (assuming both routes are defined in the same python file at the same time).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @SimonKirsten, I put in the JQuery script above.

Comment: @albert, you are completely right - I was running one or the other. I clarified the question text to reflect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the screenshot shows the output of `console.log` and thus I conclude that the `POST` is done in javascript, probably jQuery (waiting for an answer from the asker).

If this is the case, this is the expected behavior. The `POST` is done and the javascript receives the redirect and `GET`'s the redirected resource.

And the javascript is logging the html of the redirected resource.

If you want to redirect the browser you can either do this manually in the javascript (after the `POST` is done) using:

```
window.location = "/tagpage";
```

Or let the browser do it for you, in this case, the `POST` must be done through a `<form>`.

Comment: Hi @SimonKirsten, thanks for the tip. I initially tried something this (e.g. pasting such code where you see the 2-line gap in the JQuery above), at which point the redirect works. However, then the data that I am trying to store from the form using `startsession` is never recorded in `session`. My understanding then was that I should do this in Python using `redirect` if I wanted to store the data.

Comment: @atkat12 You need to do the browser redirect after the server send the response (and has done the storing in `session`). Just put the `window.location...` in the `success: function(response) {` function. This way the server has time to store the session.

Comment: @atkat12 The `$.ajax` call does not block (the request is done in the background). If you directly redirect after the ajax call the request gets immediately canceled by the browser.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: @atkat12 You are welcome. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Simon is on the right track here. You can find additional information in these previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248888/how-to-redirect-with-flask-and-jquery) about [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call), flask and redirects.

In short, you should probably just use normal html form like in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/views/).

Template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
        <dt>Title:
        <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
        <dt>Text:
        <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
      </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
  <ul class=entries>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

View function:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
                 [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

Comment: Thanks @hooligan! I think it's the redirect syntax that isn't working for me, but Simon's clarification did the trick.

Comment: Good! You can do it that way too :)